# onActivityResult works for first only problem

Tags: android

hi all
i am trying to get values from second activity in first(main) activity. for that i use onActivityResult in firstactivity. it return value to first(main) activity from second activity first time only. again i am come to firstactivity the previous value only shown.

my application flow:

first->second->first

first(main)activity:

```
   public class main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    LinearLayout l2;
    TextView tv2;
    String check=null;
//    static int value=0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        l2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout2);
        tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);


    l2.setClickable(true);

    l2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), secondactivity.class);
             startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }

    });

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data)
{
    Log.e("runapp1","onActivityResult");
    Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
    check = bundle != null ? bundle.getString("key1") : "";
    Log.e("runapp1","onActivityResult value  "+check);
    tv2.setText(check);
}    
}
```

in second activity:

```
public class secondactivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    CheckBox c1,c2;
    TextView t;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondactivity);
        c1=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        c2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

    c1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {
            c1.setChecked(true); 
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("key1",String.valueOf(c1.getText()));
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), main.class);
            myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, myIntent);
            finish();

        }

    });
    c2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View view) 
        {
            c2.setChecked(true); 
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("key1",String.valueOf(c1.getText()));
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), main.class);
            myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, myIntent);
            finish();               
        }

    });

}
}
```

please assist me.

Comment: Are you actually finishing your second activity inside its `onCreate` method? what is `c1`? Does its value actually change on each access of the second activity? Could you share the layouts please? thank you.

Comment: c1 mean CheckBox c1. and second activity is finish.

Comment: If you finish your second activity right away in its `onCreate` method, how do you expect the text of a checkbox from its view to change? If it doesn't change, the same text will be passed through the intent's extra over and over again, so no wonder you have the same value in your first activity's `onActivityResult`.

Comment: is there any way to solve this problem? i use startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0) instead of finish(). no value passed.

Comment: sure there is, but you need to elaborate your goal, since it is not clear. do you want to access the second activity, modify the checked state of the checkbox, then return to the first with the value of the affected checkbox (checked/not checked) over and over again? If so, @Rajath DSouza's solution will work for you. But don't start the first activity from the second, while an instance of the first still waits for the second to be finished. Please share more code, and if possible, your layout too, maybe we can figure out what you are really up to. thank you!

Comment: my goal is the start activity is first(main) activity. 
first activity->second activity -> first activity. this is my app flow. i edit my question for sharing more code. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following, depending on where you want to capture your checkbox's value.

```
c1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if (c1.isChecked())
        {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("key1",String.valueOf(c1.getText()));
            Intent myIntent = new Intent();
            myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, myIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }
});
```